# javascript assigning new object as object property

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var BigObject = {
    'CurrentInt': 0,
    'CurrentBool': false,
    'CurrentObject': {}
}
```

And then, I declare SomeObject like this:

```
var SomeObject = {
      'SomeString': "",
      'SomeInt': 0
}
```

These two definitions are for the objects when they're in their initial state, sort of like a type definition I guess. Now I want to assign a `new` SomeObject to `BigObject['CurrentObject']`. I tried this:

```
BigObject['CurrentObject'] = new SomeObject();
```

But it's not working. At the moment, I just do a straight assignment by reference `BigObject['CurrentObject'] = SomeObject;` and then when I need to reset the values of SomeObject, I just run a function that redeclares each property of SomeObject in its initial stage.

But how can I use the `new` keyword to create a reusable object type that's a property of BigObject.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `BigObject['CurrentObject']` can be simplified to `BigObject.CurrentObject`

Comment: @Eric: yes I know but I'm compiling my javascript with closure compiler and I need to keep it as is.

Comment: Why can't closure compiler handle that?

Comment: It can; it just renames the properties and then when I stringify the object again, the properties don't match the type definition of the server side objects. So I define my properties ['PropName'] and then the compiler does the simplification you're suggestion so that JSON.stringify keeps the property names I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're defining a type, you should use a constructor function:

```
var SomeObject = function() {
    this.someString = "";
    this.someInt = 0;
}

var BigObject = function() {
    this.currentInt = 0;
    this.currentBool = false;
    this.currentObject = new SomeObject();
}
```

Once you've defined these constructors, you can `new` them (create instances):

```
var myBigObject = new BigObject();
console.log(myBigObject.currentObject);
```

Comment: And then, can I access the properties like I do with objects?

Comment: @frenchie: On the instance, yes. And you can modify them without affecting all instances.

Answer (score 3):

`new` can only be used with a function, to run it as constructor:

```
function SomeObject() {
    this.SomeString = "";
    this.SomeInt = 0;
}
```

What you have done is equivalent to:

```
var SomeObject = new Object();
SomeObject.SomeString = "";
SomeObject.SomeInt = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript classes.

```
function SomeObject() { }
SomeObject.prototype.someString = "";
SomeObject.prototype.someInt = 0;

function BigObject(){ this.currentObj = new SomeObject; }
BigObject.prototype.currentInt = 0;
BigObject.prototype.currentBool = false;
BigObject.prototype.currentObj = null;

var a = new BigObject;

a.currentObj instanceof SomeObject;  // true
```

Comment: Don't put data in the prototype

Comment: @Esailija: Why not? That's a reasonable place for default values, isn't it?

Comment: if you put non primitive data in the prototype, bugs will happen. You don't and that's cool, but someone else might do it.

Comment: @Esailija: Hadn't thought of problems when objects are there. Upvote for you.

Comment: Primitive data belongs in the prototype since every object can share the same copy of the prototype object.  Arrays and objects (unless you really do want to share the same instance) must be defined in the constructor so each object instance will have its own copy.  (In my own code, I will define that property to be `null` in the prototype purely for documentary purposes.)